# ReactJS eslinting throwing errors on lines that don't exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm quite new to react and webpack but have used eslint and javascript for years but this is really driving me insane.

I've created my project and have a `actions.js` file in my `redux` folder and in that file all I currently have is

```
export default UPDATE_IS_LOGGED_IN = 'UPDATE_IS_LOGGED_IN';
```

I've installed airbnb eslinter and setup the webpack task like so

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
  use: ['eslint-loader', 'babel-loader']
}
```

and in my `.eslintrc` file I have

```
{
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"rules": {
    "comma-dangle" : 0,
    "no-undef": "off",
    "max-len": [1, 120, 2, {"ignoreComments": true}],
    "no-compare-neg-zero": "error",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": ["error", {
        "exceptMethods": [
            "render",
            "getInitialState",
            "getDefaultProps",
            "componentWillMount",
            "componentDidMount",
            "componentWillReceiveProps",
            "shouldComponentUpdate",
            "componentWillUpdate",
            "componentDidUpdate",
            "componentWillUnmount"
        ]
    }]
},
"extends": ["airbnb-base"]
}
```

But when I run webpack I get the following eslinting errors for the `action.js` file.

```
1:1   error  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict
3:32  error  Strings must use singlequote                   quotes
6:19  error  Unexpected chained assignment                  no-multi-assign
6:63  error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last
```

This isn't the only file its happening on its nearly every js file in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it is linting the files that webpack has already built. Try adding your build file to excludes.

Comment: @tom-maton If this was the answer can you mark it as such. Cheers!

Comment: this actually did solve this problem, I had another problem was thrown but that was due to my stupidity.